# What is the preferred method to restart networking in Ubuntu and Debian

Tags: ubuntu, debian, ubuntu-11.04

When I restart the network using:

```
/etc/init.d/networking restart
```

I get this warning:

```
 Running /etc/init.d/networking restart is deprecated because it may not enable again some interfaces
```

So what's the best way to restart the network after making changes now?

This problem also applies to Debian as the netbase package is inherited from debian.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It is just saying that the restart option is going away

```
/etc/init.d/networking stop; /etc/init.d/networking start
```

Note there is one line only! That is important when running network restart through the network.

Comment: two commands :-/ bad idea if you are in remote. Better use a one liner: `/etc/init.d/networking stop; /etc/init.d/networking start `

Comment: @hmontoliu: then again it seems wise to use the deprecated restart since you cannot forget the starting command

Comment: If you are in remote, you should always use `screen`

Comment: Screen won't really help if you shut down networking on a remote server. In this case you would have to go search for some sort of direct access, which isn't always convenient.

Comment: `stop` and `start` are obviously not deprecated but used in combination they have the same potential problem that `restart` used to have.

Answer (score 19):

Run the init.d command without parameters, it will tell you which is the usage:

```
~# /etc/init.d/networking 
Usage: /etc/init.d/networking {start|stop}
```

Seems that restart is deprecated

It is deprecated also in Debian at least since:

```
netbase (4.38) unstable; urgency=low

  * Create /etc/sysctl.d/bindv6only.conf on upgrades and new installs
    to set net.ipv6.bindv6only=1.
  * Made the init script check for swap over the network. (Closes: #540697)
  * Temporarily depend on initscripts to work around a bug in multistrap.
    (Closes: #556399)
  * etc-services: added sieve (4190/tcp).
  * etc-services: removed sieve (2000/tcp). (Closes: #555664)
  * Made the init script warn that using the force-reload and restart
    parameters is not a good idea. (Closes: #550240)

 -- Marco d'Itri <md@linux.it>  Sun, 06 Dec 2009 17:09:41 +0100
```

[The related bug #550240 here](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=550240)

Which is quite nasty. To restart netwokring from remote probably the best and securest approach will be run the following within a **screen session**:

```
~# /etc/init.d/networking stop; /etc/init.d/networking start
```

As of today's `networking` init script, `restart` and `force-reload` will work *in most* circumstances. *I guess it's reasonably safe to ignore the warning and still use restart*. However I'll go with the stop + start way :-)

```
case "$1" in
start)
    process_options

    log_action_begin_msg "Configuring network interfaces"
    if ifup -a; then
        log_action_end_msg $?
    else
        log_action_end_msg $?
    fi
    ;;

stop)
    check_network_file_systems
    check_network_swap

    log_action_begin_msg "Deconfiguring network interfaces"
    if ifdown -a --exclude=lo; then
        log_action_end_msg $?
    else
        log_action_end_msg $?
    fi
    ;;

force-reload|restart)
    process_options

    log_warning_msg "Running $0 $1 is deprecated because it may not enable again some interfaces"
    log_action_begin_msg "Reconfiguring network interfaces"
    ifdown -a --exclude=lo || true
    if ifup -a --exclude=lo; then
        log_action_end_msg $?
    else
        log_action_end_msg $?
    fi
    ;;

*)
    echo "Usage: /etc/init.d/networking {start|stop}"
    exit 1
    ;;
esac
```

Comment: Really? Restart is useful when you are working remotely!

Comment: See my edit. I agree that a bullet proof restart would be better than stop + start

Comment: I think it's worth noting that `stop` + `start` appears to do the exact same thing that `restart` would do. It does not appear to be any more safe, other than not using a deprecated option (deprecated specifically to discourage this operation).

Answer (score 5):

I use `nohup sh -c "/etc/init.d/networking stop; sleep 2; /etc/init.d/networking start"`. I add `sleep 2` because I think perhaps the issues with restart had something to do with hardware-dependent latencies, but this is unconfirmed and a semi-rule of thumb I'm somewhat ashamed to make public. So you can skip that if you're feeling rational!

Comment: so basically you're saying I have to alias restart="nohup sh -c /etc/init.d/networking stop; sleep 2; /etc/init.d/networking start" because somebody using Debian, thinks his or her job will be on the line if we actually evolve Linux beyond a hobbiest OS?

Comment: Not at all. How zany of you!

Answer (score 3):

The command below works well in a server environment, without throwing warnings. It implements both stop and start request on the networking service.

```
sudo service networking start
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to do stop && start. Anyway, it didn't for me in Debian Wheezy. Maybe it does in some other distro.

Comment: It works fine in Ubuntu

Answer (score 2):

how about `nohup sh -c "ifdown -a && ifup -a"`

Answer (score 1):

In Debian Wheezy,

```
service networking restart
```

seems to do what is expected and doesn't complain.

I guess in Jessie with systemd it may be different again.

Comment: With `systemd` it's `systemctl restart networking` iirc, but the "old" `service` way is still working.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't find the reason networking fails to restart, do it in the verbose mode inside of a `screen` session:

```
ifdown -v --force eth0; ifup -v eth0
```