# Can't Bind IP Address To Machine

Tags: linux, networking, debian, ip, ipv4

I have the following IPs but I can't bind them to my machine I am getting errors.

Here are the IPs I own.

2607:5300:60:1234::/64  -   Came with server
158.69.123.123/29                       - Bought after owner server
    167.114.123.123 - Came with server

Here is my file

```
auto eth0

iface eth0 inet static
    address 116.114.123.98
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 116.114.123.0
    broadcast 116.114.123.255
    gateway 116.114.123.254

iface eth0 inet6 static
    address 2607:5300:60:1234::
    netmask 64
    post-up /sbin/ip -family inet6 route add 2607:5300:60:79ff:ff:ff:ff:ff dev eth0
    post-up /sbin/ip -family inet6 route add default via 2607:5300:60:79ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    pre-down /sbin/ip -family inet6 route del default via 2607:5300:60:79ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    pre-down /sbin/ip -family inet6 route del 2607:5300:60:79ff:ff:ff:ff:ff dev eth0
```

Thank you for taking the time to read this question!

Here is the error I am getting

```
# /etc/init.d/networking restart
[....] Running /etc/init.d/networking restart is deprecated because it may not r[warnble some interfaces ... (warning).
[....] Reconfiguring network interfaces...RTNETLINK answers: File exists
**Failed to bring up eth0.**
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
done.
```

Comment: http://serverfault.com/q/269921/126632

Comment: That doesn't answer the question.

Comment: I understand restart is deprecated, this is the error which I put in bold. **Failed to bring up eth0.**

Comment: That's because it was already up! "restart" does not properly bring down the interface.

Comment: The addresses you list as being "yours" aren't the addresses you've got in your config file.

Comment: I changed them for privacy reasons. I have stopped and started it normally and the problem still exists.

Comment: @sugarisgood What problem? You still get precisely the same errors? Because that's the only problem you've mentioned.

Comment: @sugarisgood I take it you did *not* read http://meta.serverfault.com/a/6063/214507

Comment: Changing them consistently would be useful.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot bring up an interface that is already up. The "File exists" errors indicate that you are trying to add IP addresses and routes that are already present. Make sure the interface is down and the IPs and routes are gone and run the script and you won't get those errors.

Comment: What makes you think it is already up?

Comment: The various `File exists` errors.

Comment: But if I stop it the way you suggested and start it, still errors.

Comment: Then I guess I don't know what your question is. You might want to edit the question so that people can find out exactly what you want explained or what help you need.

Comment: Still looking for a solution to this pesky problem. No one seems to be able to figure out.

Comment: So how do I make changes to it?

Comment: Changes to what? The only question you've asked references specific errors that I've already explained. *We honestly don't know what you're asking because we've answered the only question you've asked.*

Comment: I have stopped and started it the way you want, and the error still exists so I am confused. 
root@123:~# /etc/init.d/networking stop
[ ok ] Deconfiguring network interfaces...done.
root@123:~# /etc/init.d/networking start
[....] Configuring network interfaces...RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Failed to bring up eth0.
^CRTNETLINK answers: File exists
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
done.

Comment: So why would that error show if I am stopping the interface meaning the interface isn't running.

Comment: When it says "File exists", it's because the specific thing you are creating already exist. If you down all the interfaces and remove all the IPs and routes, you won't get those errors.

Comment: How do I remove the already existing one so I can set the new one?

Comment: It depends what there is. Read the man pages for commands like `ip`.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Those file exists errors may simply indicate that `ip` command was trying to create a routing table entry, which already exists.

Comment: @kasperd Yes, exactly. Those errors indicate he's trying to do something that's already been done. The only question he's asked is why he's getting those errors, so that's why I answered it.